# Unable to get the nextstate(next url ) in CanDeactivate router guard

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, state

I have added following router guard for CanDeactivate function to validate for the unsaved changes which is working fine for me

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
      canDeactivate: () => Observable | Promise | boolean;
    }

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
    constructor( private eventService: EventsService) { }
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate, route?: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState?: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: string) {
      let sub = new Subject();
      if (BaseApiService.callStack.length || UnsavedData.isThereUnSavedData) {
          this.eventService.triggerEvent(CONST.SHOW_DATA_LOSS_MODAL, {
              showDataLossModal: true,
              sub : sub
          });
      }
      return BaseApiService.callStack.length || UnsavedData.isThereUnSavedData ? false : true;
  }
}
```

But when I detect if there are any unsaved changes I show one dialog box with yes and No buttons.

If the user clicks on yes I have to clean my unsaved changes and redirect to the URL which user has clicked. To do that I have to check what is the URL user wanted to redirect on CanDeactivate function.

**nextState?: string** But every time I get this undefined.

Please correct me if I have made any changes.

Answer (score 8):

you need to use,

**nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot**

below is the Interface definition,

```
interface CanDeactivate<T> { 
  canDeactivate(component: T, 
  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, 
  nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
}
```

Check definition [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate).

**Update**

Check below complete example,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <hr />
    <a routerLink="/home" >Home</a>
     <a routerLink="/other" >Other</a>
  <hr />
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }

@Component({
  template: `<h1>Home</h1>
  
  <a routerLink="/other" >Go to Other from Home</a>
  `
})
class HomeComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `<h1>Other</h1>
  `
})
class OtherComponent {
}

@Injectable()
class CanDeactivateHome implements CanDeactivate<HomeComponent> {
  canDeactivate(
    component: HomeComponent,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
   
   console.log(component);
   console.log(currentRoute);
   console.log(currentState);
   console.log(nextState);
   
   return true;
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateHome] },
  { path: 'other',  component: OtherComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent, OtherComponent ],
  providers: [CanDeactivateHome],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Check this [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/y8CN9j48lUcf2SxJJLhP?p=preview)

Comment: @Rhushikesh, I have added a simple example with Plunker,you can see in console logs next state is printing when going to route other than Home, can you check if you are doing something similar, if not you can edit Plunker to reproduce your issue,then may be I can help, Cheers!!